# JDBC: Oracle Application Server and "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" error

Tags: java, database, oracle, jakarta-ee, oas

I am getting the error: "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" from a web application deployed in Oracle Application Server 10g.  The database is local, so there shouldn't be any connection issues.

First test: I can connect to the DB no problem from SQL plus, run queries, etc.
Second test: I can connect to the database no problem from a locally installed JDeveloper on the server, and run queries, etc. no problem.  This works with the short JDBC scring, and the long one (shown below).

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=abcd)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))

Yet when I run the web app, it gives the above error.  It seems too generic for me to do anything about.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?  I assume that Oracle logs failed connection attempts somewhere, but I couldn't find anything relevant in the databases alert.log file.

It is possible that the problem is that the application is using an old jsdk, but I would assume that then some version mismatch error would be given instead of a "network connection" message.

Edit: I don't know whether this is an OAS problem or a problem with the specific Web Application, I would like to figure this out first, as it seems it should be easy.  In WebSphere, there is a "test connection" button to dest data-sources you have added, but it seems there is no such functionality in OAS10?  Somehow I think there must be, and I am just missing it because I am not an OAS expert.

Edit 2: I installed JDevelop on a remote machine and connected to the database with no problems, so I know for sure it isn't an issue with the database connectivity itself - it seems like it must be a problem within OAS?

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem(able to connect through client but not web application) with Oracle XE when running with default configuration. Increasing number of sessions and processes solved my problem. Check this http://www.markcallen.com/oracle/oracle-xe-tuning.

Comment: +1 i have had that happen, too. Problem seems to be when using a connection pool that starts out wanting many connections all at once. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Hmm that was a good suggestion, but looking at the numbers, they seems quite a bit higher than what is in the linked sample.  Yes, on Windows 2003.

Comment: SQL> show parameters sessions

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ----------
java_max_sessionspace_size           integer     0
java_soft_sessionspace_limit         integer     0
license_max_sessions                 integer     0
license_sessions_warning             integer     0
logmnr_max_persistent_sessions       integer     1
sessions                             integer     445
shared_server_sessions               integer

Comment: <code>
SQL> show parameters processes

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ----------
aq_tm_processes                      integer     0
db_writer_processes                  integer     1
gcs_server_processes                 integer     0
job_queue_processes                  integer     10
log_archive_max_processes            integer     2
processes                            integer     400
SQL> 
</code>

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that Oracle logs failed connection attempts somewhere

It would show up in listener.log, but with the error you get, it seems doubtful that JDBC could even contact the listener.

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=abcd)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))

Is that the same string you use for the web app?

Comment: Well I tried with that long string, and the short version like:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:abcd

Both work fine on the JDev, and both give the same error with the Web App.  I also tried localhost vs. the IP address.  Same result- both are fine in JDev, and both throw errors in the app.  

I am pulling my hair out because I find it difficult to believe that they built OAS without a "test connection" button *somewhere* in the management interface.

Comment: did you get anything in listener.log?

Comment: The reason I wanted to check the long was to see if the connection was somehow rejected by the listener (though I can't imagine it would be, since it's a local connection).

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with localhost and 127.0.0.1 which go away when using a more definitive host name or address [IE a name that other machines would know the host as.]. I think it was to do with how the name was resolved (eg locally or off to a name server or similar).

Not a java person, but is there any way to simply ping localhost/127.0.0.1 from the java and see whether there's a response.

Comment: Hmm, I will certainly give this a try to see if it helps.  If it is such a simple solution, I will feel a bit silly, but be happy to have the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to fix the issueis to update Hosts file at WAS Server with entries for DB servers as shown below:
111.222.333.444 serverab.abc.com serverab