# Hibernate can't open a connection with oracle 10g using jndi in JBoss

Tags: hibernate, jboss, connection, jndi

I've got an application that runs on JBoss 4.2.3 and connects to an Oracle 10g DB.  We refactored the application to use spring roo.  Prior to trying to configure for jndi, we were using regular db connection strings and it was fine.  But now we're trying to use jndi and while JBoss registers the jndi and creates the data source bean, when hibernate actually has to open a connection, it fails to open.

This is the configuration for persistence unit

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitDev" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:jdbc.DataSourceDev"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:jdbc.DataSourceDev"/>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/Manager1Factory"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:jdbc.DataSourceDev</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <!--DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

application context defines the db beans:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiDataSource2" jndi-name="${database.jndiName}"/>


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${hibernate.persistenceunit}"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource2"/>
</bean>
```

I'm at a loss as to why hibernate seems unable to open a connection.

Edit: this is the log:

2011-12-05 12:34:51,577 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:190)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:619)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:264)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:575)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:347)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:330)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:402)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:849)

<-- cut -->

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:172)

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why you didn't post any exceptions or log traces.

Comment: Check if your problem is same as this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219417/jdbc-oracle-application-server-and-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out:

below is my configuration.

```
   <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitDev" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="dbjndiName"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        <!--DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and then the hibernate.cfg.xml is empty

my application context is defined with the following beans:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitDev"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">file:c:/temp</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="dbjndiName"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I think in this case it was a case of less was more as well as not using Java EE JNDI lookup and picking the right data source bean class.